# Google OpenSocial API issue about Curl Method

Tags: php, curl, oauth, google-api-client

I am trying to build an application using Google Opensocial API.
But when i make a POST request with following CURL headers, i am getting 405 Method not allowed error :

```
CURLOPT_URL : http://www.orkut.com/social/rpc/
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS : [{"method":"people.get","id":"self","params":{"userId":["@me"],"groupId":"@self","fields":["displayName","currentLocation","thumbnailUrl","gender","name"]}},{"method":"people.get","id":"friends","params":{"userId":["@me"],"groupId":"@friends","fields":["displayName","currentLocation","thumbnailUrl","gender","name"],"count":300}}]
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST : POST
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER : true
CURLOPT_USERAGENT : osapi 1.0
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION : 1
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER : false
CURLOPT_HEADER : true
CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT : true
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER : Array
        (
            [0] => Authorization: OAuth oauth_body_hash="A3ZOHT4b3YMOzEfg+2j3v+N302E=", oauth_nonce="6ad533sdfsb9261ssdfsdf29af7d", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_timestamp="1318236734", oauth_consumer_key="www.mydomain.com", oauth_token="1%2FKhAasdfsd8YX2bfsdfsdf6MsdfsfsdfsdfJYyULWUog", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="osdf4pShOsdfsdf88nnpwsdfsdf9g%3D"
            [1] => Content-Type: application/json
            [2] => Content-Length: 0
            [3] => User-Agent: osapi 1.0
        )
```

Following is the CURL-POST response I am recieving :

```
["http_code"] =>  int(405)
["data"] => string(12614) 
    "HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Length: 12462
    Date: Tue, 14 Jun 2011 08:07:58 GMT
    Server: GFE/2.0
```

I asked about this issue on Google Codes forum and they told me to remove following line from CURL request as my website is hosted on hostgator.

```
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST : POST
```

I tried above thing but still i am getting 405 Method not allowed error. Kindly assist me further on this issue.
Do i need to modify my PHP-CURL code above to send POST request? If so, then please help me..

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Social specification](http://opensocial-resources.googlecode.com/svn/spec/1.1/Core-API-Server.xml#urlAddressing) has an example in which `people.get` is requested with GET, not via POST. Generally keep in mind that `GET` is for requesting information, while `POST` is for changing existing information.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Can you please give an example with code? How can i call people.get method using curl in above scenario? thanks in advance.